# Is Vimeo SDK available for android?

Tags: android, sdk, vimeo

Just like facebook SDK, is there any SDK available to integrate vimeo videos in android application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API **is open to any language** as it answers to HTTP calls.

> http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple

if you need to **show private videos** as well, you need to use the Advanced API and this is a little bit more complicate as it's more secure. *The Advanced API uses OAuth 1.0 for authentication.*

> http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced

What you probably want to know is if there's an **Android Wrapper** of the Vimeo API **witch I know none**, but as said, **it's simple calls that sends you JSON or XML objects** and if using the Advanced API, there are [plenty of libraries](http://oauth.net/code/) to handle the authentication.

Comment: Here is a Java/Android wrapper for the Vimeo API: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java

Comment: Can you please give me exact example reference with using I can Integrate Vimeo API (Upload video to vimeo from my android app, list all videos to my app)

Comment: Did anybody have sample to do the same as what @JalpeshKhakhi explain ?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown just follow the docs, they are very precise on what you need to do: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

Comment: yes, but i no need to upload videos from app, i want to play the video with respect to the video ID.

Comment: @ArnoldBrown then you don't even need the API ... only if it's a private view you will need it

Comment: So, is it possible to load a vimeo url in video player directly?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown if it's public, it's just like Youtube and such ... check the source code for example https://player.vimeo.com/video/103266746 tough for best UI, you should use the embed code, like we do with Youtube videos

Comment: Source code!!!!

Comment: yes i can play the url in webview ...

Comment: the videos are private only there is a web portal to upload, and api for  mobile apps.